# match colors with categories r

Tags: r, graph, colors

Upd: I added a reproducible code.

---

Dear all, 
I am trying to match colors and categories. I have 7 spreadsheets with the data. Each spreadsheet is data on population numbers of a given species in several countries. I'd like to plot population number of each spp in each country against time, every country in a different color (see below). The thing is, a list of countries varies for each species, so I can't just make a loop: in case of wild boar, Poland will be a first color, but in case of red deer, it will be a third one. An example:

```
year    lv      lt      pl      uk      es
1974    21578   9250    2700    17610   8900
1975    19955   8800    3300    14280   9300
```

I created a spreadsheet to match colors and country names:

```
code    col.num
cz  1
hu  2
pl  3
sl  4
lv  5
lt  6
es  7
ro  8
uk  9
```

Here is a code to match colors and country names (it creates 3 graphs, first one is % of numbers relatively to a number in the year of 1990):

```
    par(mar=c(5.1, 3.5, 4.5, 2), mfrow = c(3,3))
col.num <- 1:9
code <- c('cz', 'hu', 'pl', 'sl', 'lv', 'lt', 'es', 'ro', 'uk')
cntr.num <- array(0,c(9,2))
cntr.num[,1] <- col.num; cntr.num[,2] <- code
cntr.num <- as.data.frame(cntr.num)

year <- 1975:2010
# an example for wild boar
cz <- sample(5000:30000, 36); pl <- sample(5000:30000, 36); hu <- sample(5000:30000, 36); sl <- sample(5000:30000, 36)
lv <- sample(5000:30000, 36); lt <- sample(5000:30000, 36); es <- sample(5000:30000, 36); ro <- sample(5000:30000, 36)
wb <- cbind(year, cz,pl, hu, sl, lv, lt, es, ro)
wb <-as.data.frame(wb)
colnames(wb) <- c('year', 'cz', 'pl', 'hu', 'sl', 'lv', 'lt', 'es', 'ro')

plot(wb[,1], (wb[,2]/wb[,2][wb[,1] == 1990])*100, type = "l", ylim=c(0,310), col=1)
for (i in 3:(dim(wb)[2])) { lines(wb[,1], (wb[,i]/wb[,i][wb[,1] == 1990])*100, col = cntr.num[,1][cntr.num[,2]==colnames(wb)[i]]) }
plot(wb[,1], wb[,2], type = "o", main = "WILD BOAR", col=1, ylim=c(0,250000))
for (i in 3:5) { lines(wb[,1], wb[,i], col = cntr.num[,1][cntr.num[,2]==colnames(wb)[i]]) }

plot(wb[,1], wb[,6], type = "o", col=6, , ylim=c(0,70000))
for (i in 7:(dim(wb)[2])) {lines(wb[,1], wb[,i], col = cntr.num[,1][cntr.num[,2]==colnames(wb)[i]]) }
```

it runs, and gives me a graph, but colors don't match. Looks like R just makes them up. 
Could anybody help me with the colors? Thank you! I found some similar questions but not exactly what I need.

Comment: Make a simple example that is reproducible. Posting code with `file.choose()` or names of files on your computer is _not_ reproducible.

Comment: Have you checked that `cntr.num$col.num[cntr.num$code==names(wb)[i]]` is giving you the number are expecting?  Again without a reproducible example, it's hard to help...

Comment: Dear BondedDust and Jthorpe, it's a good point about a reproducable code. I added it.

Comment: And yes, i get correct numbers but wrong colors.

Comment: Use `i` instead of `cntr.num[,1][cntr.num[,2]==colnames(wb)[i]]`. Also see `?palette` for changing the default colors.

Comment: Thank you lukeA, but it's not going to work. The thing is, a list of countries varies for each species, so I can't just make a loop: in case of wild boar, Poland will be a first color, but in case of red deer, it will be a third one.